# show that group of 108 is not simple

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I have already gone thru this link [Show that a group of order $108$ has a normal subgroup of order $9$ or $27$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091483/show-that-a-group-of-order-108-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-9-or-27)

But i did not understand how $H \cap K$ is normal in H and K
My understanding to show : g$(H \cap K) g^{-1} \in H$ it means how can we show  g$K g^{-1} \in H$
Pls clarify

Comment: As indicated in that answer, it is because the index of the subgroup is the smallest prime dividing the order of the group. It is a general result that such subgroups are normal.

Comment: This is known as the 'Strong Calley Theorem'. See this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index .